# Из pupeteer получить свойство из элемента со страницы

Tags: javascript, node.js, vue.js, dom, puppeteer

**Expected result:** Мне нужно получить элемент  `#app` with its `__vue__` property

**Actual result** я получаю undefined с const `data`

**Note** Если я возвращаю `document.querySelector('#app')` я получаю тот же результат - undefined.

````
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');
(async () => {
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch({ headless: false });
  const page = await browser.newPage();
  await page.goto('https://www.google.com/'); // url for example
  const functionToInject =  function(){
    return document.querySelector('#app').__vue__.$root.$options._base;
  }

  const data = await page.evaluate(functionToInject);

  console.log(data)
  await browser.close();
})();```
````

Comment: А какой тип данных находится в `._base`?

Comment: @vsemozhebuty находится конструктор Vue .

Comment: Дело в том, что передавать в функцию, выполняемую в `page.evaluate()`, и получать из неё можно только такие данные, которые подлежат сериализации (грубо говоря, которые не пропадают в JSON). Поэтому ни функции, ни DOM-элементы, ни структуры с циклическими ссылками передавать туда-сюда не получится (об этом есть в документации).

Comment: Но можно попробовать использовать [`page.evaluateHandle()`](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/blob/main/docs/api.md#pageevaluatehandlepagefunction-args), хоть оперировать JSHandle чуть сложнее.

Comment: @vsemozhebuty можешь написать пример как достать конструктор Vue с помощью evuluateHandle ? это было бы хорошим ответом

Comment: Мне трудно понять контекст вашей задачи, я не знаю Vue, поэтому не пытаюсь отвечать полноценно. Но вы можете просто заменить `page.evaluate` на `page.evaluateHandle` и по идее в `data` получите ссылку на несериализируемые данные из контекста браузера. Эту ссылку потом можно использовать в других методах, которые могут работать с JSHandle (в документации это всегда оговаривается).

Comment: @vsemozhebuty на деле нужно просто достать свойство елемента . Cпасибо большое,  я попробую этот способ

Comment: Если не будет получатся, задайте новый вопрос или отредактируйте этот с более подробным описанием и чуть более расширенным кодом)

Comment: @vsemozhebuty дело в том что пока кода больше нет пока не возьму данные из браузера)

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/127143/discussion-between---and-vsemozhebuty).